# How to reduce quantity in react.js and node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

**react.js**
As you can see in the react code, I am trying to reduce the quantity, but I struggle to do it in react. what I want is if click button then quantity should be reduced 1 by 1. I think I am

```js
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0)

const handleDelivery = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const deliveryInventoryItem = inventoryItem.quantity(quantity-1);

  const url = `http://localhost:5000/inventoryItem/${inventoryItemId}`;

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(deliveryInventoryItem)
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
    console.log('success', data);
    alert('users added successfully!');
    event.target.reset();
    setQuantity(data)
  })

}
```

**node.js**

```js
app.put('/inventoryItem/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  const deliveryInventoryItem = req.body;
  console.log(id, updatedInventoryItem);
  const filter = {_id: ObjectId(id)};
  const options = {upsert: true};
  const updatedDoc = {
    $set: {
      quantity: deliveryInventoryItem.quantity
    }
  };
  const result = await inventoryItemCollection.updateOne(filter, updatedDoc, options);
  res.send(result);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

In mongoDB, use $inc to increase or descrease quantity, see more: [MongoDB $inc docs](https://db.products.updateOne(%20%20%20%20%7B%20sku:%20%22abc123%22%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%7B%20$inc:%20%7B%20quantity:%20-2,%20%22metrics.orders%22:%201%20%7D%20%7D%20))

In React app:

```
const quantityChange = -1 // If you want decrease 1 by 1 or any number you want increase or decrease by this number
fetch(url, {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
   },
  body: JSON.stringify(quantityChange)
}).then().catch()
...
```

In Nodejs App, edit your updatedDoc:

```
const { quantityChange } = res.body
const updatedDoc = {
    $inc: {
      quantity: quantityChange
    }
  };
```